# How to find the derivative of an integral whose integrand is a composition of the integral limits?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, leibniz-integral-rule

Given a function $q=q(t, e)$, where $ e= e(t, v(\tau))$, such that $q = q(t, e(t, v(\tau)))$, how to find the expression for $\frac{dQ}{d \tau}$ if

$$Q(\tau) = \int_0^\tau q(t, e(t, v(\tau))) dt$$

such that

$$ \frac{dQ}{d \tau} = \frac{d}{d\tau} \left( \int_0^\tau q(t, e(t, v(\tau))) dt  \right) $$

where the integrand is a function of the integral limits through composition?

I'm thinking that the Leibniz integral rule might come in handy (link below), but I am having troubles applying it due to the composition. Any ideas, tips, or thoughts are appreciated.

Leibniz integral rule link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
F(a, b) = \int_0^a q(t, e(t, v(b))) dt
$$
Then $Q(\tau) = F(\tau, \tau)$, and using the chain rule from multivariable calculus we have
$$
\frac{dQ}{d\tau} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a}\frac{da}{d\tau} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}\frac{db}{d\tau}.
$$
Here, $a(\tau) = b(\tau) = \tau$ and hence
$$
\frac{dQ}{d\tau} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a}(\tau, \tau) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial b}(\tau, \tau) \\
= q(t, e(v(\tau))) + \int_0^\tau \frac{\partial q}{\partial e}\frac{\partial e}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{d\tau}dt,
$$
where I've assumed all the functions are sufficiently differentiable to allow differentiating under the integral sign.

Comment: Awesome! I think I have understood your derivation (which was thorough and easy to understand). I have one question: why in the final integrand is there a full derivative dv/dtau instead of a partial derivative @v/@tau? (I couldn't figure out how to do formulas in comments, so I denoted the partial derivative with @)

Comment: I assumed that $v$ was just a function of $\tau$, so the partial derivatives and the full derivatives are the same thing

Comment: Right =). Thanks.